# Postgresql Serial Daily Count of Records

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, left-join, recursive-query

I am trying to get a total count of records from 1st Jan till date, without skipping dates and returning 0 for dates that have no records.

I have tried the following: orders is an example table and orderdate is a timestamp column

```
with days as (
  select generate_series(
    date_trunc('day','2020-01-01'::timestamp),
    date_trunc('day', now()),
    '1 day'::interval
  ) as day
)
select
  days.day,
  count(orders.id)
from days
left outer join orders on date_trunc('day', orders.orderdate) = days.day
where orders.orders_type='C'
group by 1
```

The issue is that dates are skipped.
yet if i execute:

```
select generate_series(
    date_trunc('day','2020-01-01'::timestamp),
    date_trunc('day', now()),
    '1 day'::interval
  )
```

i get the right series with no dates skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` condition should belong to the `on` clause of the `left join`, ie this:

```
from days
left outer join orders on date_trunc('day', orders.orderdate) = days.day
where orders.orders_type='C'
```

Should be written:

```
from days
left outer join orders 
    on  date_trunc('day', orders.orderdate) = days.day
    and orders.orders_type='C'
```

Notes:

- you don't actually need a cte here, you can put `generate_series()` directly in the `from` clause
- the date join condition can be optimized to an index-friendly expression that avoids `date_trunc()`
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write

You could write the query as:

```
select d.day, count(o.id)
from generate_series(date '2020-01-01', now(), '1 day') as d(day)
left outer join orders o
    on  o.orderdate >= d.day
    and o.orderdate <  d.day + '1 day'::interval
    and o.orders_type='C'
group by d.day
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, both solutions worked. though the cte seemed a lot faster. i understand taking advantage of any index on the date join, but there is no index on this column.